# Cannot start HBase master after migrating to Ranger authorisation

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-ranger

I've been trying to secure my Horton cluster such that authorisation goes via Ranger for file access. I have followed the best practise guide available on the Hortonworks site (https://hortonworks.com/blog/best-practices-in-hdfs-authorization-with-apache-ranger/). After doing so, however, I find that HBase is unable to start.

The error that I am getting is:

```
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=hbase, access=EXECUTE, inode="/apps":hdfs:hdfs:d---------
```

I have configured Ranger to allow the hbase user full access (RWX) to /apps, however the system appears to be bypassing this policy in favor of HDFS permissions:

[image: Ranger audit]

It appears to be allowing all other access types, including READ_EXECUTE, but is ignoring the permission to EXECUTE from within /apps.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to change permissions on /apps from user hdfs. hdfs dfs -chmod a+rx /apps

Comment: This countermands the stated best practise for setting permissions on /apps, as noted in the linked article from Hortonworks. It's likely that it will fix the problem, however I would prefer to follow best practise.

Comment: FYI this is how is set /apps on our Hortonworks (supported) secured production cluster:

drwxr-xr-x+  - yarn   hadoop          0 2018-10-29 14:43 /apps